# What is "a quiet ping"?

Tags: vocabulary

What is a quiet ping? Is it the noise the page makes when you turn it?

> There was a quiet ping as Veronica turned her reader on and advanced
>   to the next chapter.

Thanks

Comment: I would interpret that sentence to mean that the "ping" was heard when the reader was turned on, although the device could also make a "ping" every time a user advances to a new page or chapter. In any event, a _ping_ is not the sound of a paper page turning.

Answer (score 1):

A ping is a high pitched mechanical sound of brief duration.  A quiet ping is one at low volume.

Try searching for "ping" at this page:  http://www.findsounds.com/ISAPI/search.dll

The second link should give you this sound: http://www.soundjig.com/mp3/soundfx/beeps/beep1.mp3

This is a good example of a quiet ping.